# Django Rest Framework error 'django.core.urlsolvers'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement Django REST Framework to my application, but facing this issue during the run-time. Any suggestion? I am using Django 2.0.2

**Error Code:**

```
File "/Users/../project1/blogs/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from rest_framework.reverse import reverse as api_reverse
File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse as django_reverse
ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

Comment: What is your DRF version?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the DRF version was old. I upgraded my DRF version using pip install -U djangorestframework to 3.8.2. Now it does not show that error anymore

Comment: I saw that, but it was different